# Can i use Trident 6.0 in Windows Forms App C# (.NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, winforms

Trident (also known as MSHTML) is the name of the layout engine for the Microsoft Windows version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)

I wanted to know how or if i can use Trident version 6.0 (IE 10 equivalent) in C# Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework 4)

EDIT: I wanted to implement WebSockets and local storage for my Windows Forms App. And i need new trident for that i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebBrowser Control to show html to your end users. I suppose that the rendering engine will depend of the installed version of IE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`WebBroser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class. I found that to force the engine version used to render in your app you should update `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` registry key for IE. Check [this article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) for reference. There is also [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) with all allowed values.

Of course mashine running your software should have this version of IE installed.

**EDIT:**
I found [old article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1102/Using-the-WebBrowser-control-in-NET) that may be helpfull. As far as I understand, you can include needed DLLs with those commandline commands:

```
aximp c:\windows\system\shdocvw.dll
tlbimp mshtml.tlb
```

However, I have not tested this, so you can give it a try and tell if it works or not.

Comment: thanks for reply. but that doesn't guarantee it. I hope someone will answer how to link custom "mshtml.dll" that guarantees browser support.